# Detect and show error message when google maps is not showing on a Blackberry

Tags: google-maps, blackberry

After doing research I have discovered that Google Maps (on a webpage) will not work with most or all of Blackberrys. It appears that this is a result of the lack of significant Javascript on the Blackberry browser.

Is there any code that I can use to detect whether the maps are being displayed on a device and put up an error message accordingly. (iPhone and Android are targets too)

I tried something like the below but the Blackberry has some Javascript os the "Hello World" got dispalyed properly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way we got this to work was to set a timeout function that triggers on startup which checks a variable which is set after the maps have initialised.

If the variable is set then the map loaded and if not it didn't. It can be a long wait but at least we set something up where we could alret the user.